# Update model from Firebird database

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-4, firebird, ado.net-entity-data-model, entity-data-model

I would like to update model from a Firebird database in Visual Studio. I followed this tutorial: https://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/connection_to_firebird_in_visual_studio_2017_via_ddex_provider.html
In Server Explorer, I successfully connected to database. When I added the ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the project, and I would like to use EF Designer from database, then I would like to change the connection/Data source (or create an empty model, then I would like to upgrade from database), it doesn't showing up the Firebird Data Source:

[image]

Setup:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.9.2
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.04.084
- LCPI Data OLE DB Visual Studio Extension [v2][Provider: FW4.6.2][DDEX: FW4.7.2] - 1.21.1.4247

NuGet Packages:

- EntityFramework.Firebird v7.10.1
- FirebirdSQL.Data.FirebirdClient

Comment: You may want to consider asking your question on the [Firebird-net-provider Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/firebird-net-provider)

Comment: I see "Data provider: .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server". Are there other options in this combo box? Documentation mentioned in the question definitely show usage of "LCPI .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB [FW4.6.2]".

Comment: No, there aren't other options in combobox, and the other two data source has too only this one option.

Comment: In this case you'd better try to do what is written in the tutorial exactly. Obviously Firebird provider cannot appear among MS SQL data sources.